# Track changes in a Java source

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to track changes in a java source file in my eclipse plugin to update some references I keep of methods/variables/types if they are renamed.
I am interested in the IJavaElement before it was changed and how it is after the change.

I found

```
JavaCore.addElementChangedListener(/**/, ElementChangedEvent.POST_RECONCILE);
```

to obtain notifications of changes. The JavaElementDelta that the listener-event provide enables me to get the IJavaElement. Unfortunately, the notifications are difficult to handle.
For instance, if the user renames a method and pauses for a fraction of a second an event is fired and once the user finish typing the new name a further event is fired. That makes it necessary to track all those (incomplete) changes. That is cumbersome. 
Is there a better way to obtain the before-after name an IJavaElement in a source file?

Comment: Can you explain why this is "cumbersome"? (You cannot change the reconciliation timeout...)